# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 408 (Request Timeout) safari 11.10

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, macos, safari

I am getting error while uploading file through ajax in mac safari browser 11.10 it gives error as

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 408
>   (Request Timeout)

my code as given below

```
var formData = new FormData($("#designer_product_updateform")[0]);
      var prodesc = CKEDITOR.instances['product_edesc'].getData();
        formData.append("product_edesc",prodesc);
        formData.append('action', "updateDesignerProduct");

        $("#addproducttabajaxloader").css("display","block");
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"includes/ajax_product.php",
            data:formData,
          cache:false,
            contentType:false,
            processData:false,
            success:function(response){
            $("#addproducttabajaxloader").css("display","none");

              var parseval = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
              var code = parseval.code;
              var message = parseval.message;
              if(code == "201")
              {
                var message_html = '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" id="attdone"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>'+ message +'</div>';
                jQuery("#yajaxmessage").html("");
                jQuery("#yajaxmessage").html(message_html);
                setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = "myaccount.php?t=pl"; }, 1000);
              }
              else if(code == "200")
              {
                var message_html = '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" id="attdone"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>'+ message +'</div>';
                jQuery("#yajaxmessage").html("");
                jQuery("#yajaxmessage").html(message_html);
              } 
            }
        })
        return false;
    }
  });
```

Please help me i tierd of using different solutions

thanks in advance

Comment: If you're getting a timeout error it would seem to indicate a server issue, not a JS one. Is it a large file that you're attempting to upload? If so, increase the allowed timeout in the server configuration.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan No its a 200kb image also its working on all browser except safari browser